# Select case , what is the right format

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2013

i've been studying on how to get the value inserted in my textbox so i can find it in my database. So i can end with a result.

```
(Table name = rooms)
(Table contents = Roomnumber,Status,Roomtype)
(Roomnumber = 201,202,203)
(Status= Available,Occupied,Reserved)
```

Here is my code:

```
myConnection.Open()
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select  [Roomnumber] = '" & textboxt1.text & "' ,[Status] FROM [rooms]", myConnection)
Dim dt As New DataTable
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)

For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows

    Select Case row("Roomnumber").ToString()

        Case "textbox1.text"
            Select Case row("Status").ToString().ToLower()

                Case "available"
                    Msgbox("hello")

                Case "occupied"
                    Msgbox ("hi")

                Case "reserved"
                    Msgbox ("input code")

            End Select
    End Select
Next
myConnection.Close()

End Sub
```

I want my Roomnumber depend on what is in my textbox, and look in the database for its Status. My error is where i put "textbox.text"

Comment: You should start by studying a tutorial in "Beginning with SQL" or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, i change the format of my "cmd"

Here is the correct code:

```
myConnection.Open()
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select  [Roomnumber] ,[Status] FROM [rooms] WHERE Roomnumber = " & textbox1.text & "", myConnection)
Dim dt As New DataTable
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)

For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows

Select Case row("Roomnumber").ToString()

    Case "textbox1.text"
        Select Case row("Status").ToString().ToLower()

            Case "available"
                Msgbox("hello")

            Case "occupied"
                Msgbox ("hi")

            Case "reserved"
                Msgbox ("input code")

        End Select
End Select
Next
    myConnection.Close()

End Sub
```